# Synchronus Buck Converter

Tags: arduino, buck

So i am designing a Synchronus Buck converter 12V - 5V with 12 W of power at the output. This means that my output current will be on average 2.4 A.

Now for the feedback I am using an Arduino. I will be connecting this output voltage to an input pin of the Arduino (using a voltage divider to bring the voltage down to a 0-5V level). Since the current at the output is 2.4A, I assume my arduino will probably burn out.

So should I use a voltage buffer at the end of my circuit before i connect it to the arduino?

Any tips on how I can reduce this current going into my Arduino pin? Also any other PIC i could use other than an Arduino?

Comment: What is the switching frequency of your buck going to be?

Comment: What leads you to believe that the Arduino input pin, with its very high impedance, would try and sink 2.4A?!

Comment: Am I confused, or is Vout already 5V?

Comment: Most Arduino pins can source or sink around 40mA as outputs. Using the pins as analog inputs, you don't care how much current is available, you only need to read the voltage level; 0.000000001A @ 5V = 5V

Comment: Input leakage current for the ATTiny is typically <0.05uA and 1uA MAX. ATTiny pins, as inputs, "demand"(allow) only 0.00000005A to flow through the Arduino to ground.

Comment: Use rail to rail op-amp....connect output to Ardino

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdRbyV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>